# How do I get Post data from my HTTP context object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a POC using a very old asp.net application that runs winforms, and adding a REST API to it. I have so far been successful up until this one endpoint, and it is not giving me my data back in my controller.

I have more experience in an MVC framework and web API then the current implementation I am working in. What I need help with is how I can get my data sent back to the server.

Here is my code:
this is the equivalent of my global asax file

```
      class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
    var setPatient = function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:9000/api/context/readPtnt?contextData=&type=context",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            jsonData: JSON.stringify({
                firstName: $('#fName').val(),
                lastName: $('#lName').val(),
                ID: $('#ID').val(),
                DOB: $('#DOB').val(),
                SSN: $('#SSN').val(),
                MRN: $('#MRN').val()  
            })

        }
    })
        .done(successPatientSet)
        .fail(errorFn)
        .always(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        });
}
//click
$("#btnSetPatientData").on("click", setPatient);
```

and my controller code:

```
         [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/context/readPtnt")]
    public string ReadPtnt(string contextData, string type)
    {

        try
        {
           var patientInfo = PatientContext.Create(contextData);
```

I can successfully hit the back end, but I get nothing in the contextData variable, when I try to change that variable name I get 404's. I have tried all sorts of variations from different iterations of my JQuery, as well as pure javascript Ajax calls. The REST middleware that we are using is OWIN. I am stumped, any input would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What is `asp.net application that runs winforms`? Those are two different technologies.

Comment: What I meant to say was its an old application that runs winforms in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need enable CORS support
To enable CORS support, add the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors NuGet package to your project.

Add this code to your configuration:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // New code
    config.EnableCors();
}
```

To enable cross-origin requests, add the [EnableCors] attribute to your Web API controller or controller method:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // Controller methods not shown...
}
```

Enabling Globally
The method described above can also be used to enable CORS across the API without annotating each controller:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://example.com", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
}
```

For more information, see the official Web API documentation.

Comment: thank you for your post, but I have CORS enabled in my Startup.cs

Comment: This actually ended up being the problem, I had enabled Cors, but not added the reference to the project suggested. DOH! Facepalm.